# Deployment failed on Wildfly 9

Tags: deployment, eclipselink, wildfly, java-ee-7

I once had this issue with wildfly 8 but was solved include eclipselink.jar in $WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main and updating the module.xml with the resource root

```
<resource-root path="eclipselink.jar" />
```

and including on my ejb module's POM.xml

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>  
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>  
        <version>2.6.0</version>  
        <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency>
```

This works fine in Wildfly 8.*. Unfortunately employing the same technic for Wildfly 9CR1 has consistently failed the with log below:

```
08:52:31,028 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."rga-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rga-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "rga-ear-1.0.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.persistenceprovider.PersistenceProviderLoader.loadProviderModuleByName(PersistenceProviderLoader.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:998)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.nextPhaseDependsOnPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1046)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider have different Class objects for the type javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2964)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 13 more

08:52:31,195 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "rga-ear-1.0.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"rga-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"rga-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"rga-ear-1.0.ear\"
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider could not be instantiated
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method \"org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;\" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider have different Class objects for the type javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil used in the signature"}}
```

I have also tried removing the

```
<resource-root path="eclipselink.jar" />
eclipselink.jar
```

But get a different error Persistence Provider Not Found.
Could this be a Wildfly bug or there's something I am not doing right?

Comment: Looks like you're loading two different `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` classes. Does eclipse link package this within it's archive?

Comment: No, eclipselink.jar dose not have javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Comment: Is it maybe packaged in your EAR? There's definitely two copies of it on your class path.

Comment: I can't really tell, but the funny part is that the same app.ear is deployed successfully on Wildfly 8.2 and with similar setting on the standalone.xml.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same issue, and resolved using wf9 docs: 
[wildlfy 9 eclipselink](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink)

basically, instead `<resource-root path="eclipselink.jar" />`

place this

```
<resource-root path="eclipselink.jar">
        <filter>
                <exclude path="javax/**" />
        </filter>
        </resource-root>
```

By the way, I'm using eclipslink 2.5.2