# Joss eap 6.4 upgrade to 7.2 :javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider not a subtype

Tags: jboss, eclipselink

Jboss eap 6.4 upgrade to 7.2 deploy ear error

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"WLS_DOM_SPS.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"WLS_DOM_SPS.ear\"
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider not a subtype"}}
```

eclipse link module config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="eclipselink-2.1.2_TMSModified1.jar">
            <filter>
                <exclude path="javax/**" />
            </filter>
        </resource-root>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

jboss eap 6.4 can deploy success. Don't know where the problem is.

javax.persistence.jar-javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

```
package javax.persistence.spi;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public interface PersistenceProvider {
    EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String var1, Map var2);

    EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo var1, Map var2);

    ProviderUtil getProviderUtil();
}
```

eclipselink-org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package org.eclipse.persistence.jpa;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.ClassTransformer;
import javax.persistence.spi.LoadState;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo;
import javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil;
import org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceInitializationHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.SEPersistenceUnitInfo;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved;

public class PersistenceProvider implements javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider, ProviderUtil {
    protected PersistenceInitializationHelper initializationHelper = null;

    public PersistenceProvider() {
        this.initializationHelper = new PersistenceInitializationHelper();
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String emName, Map properties) {
        ClassLoader classloader = this.initializationHelper.getClassLoader(emName, properties);
        return this.createEntityManagerFactory(emName, properties, classloader);
    }

    protected EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String emName, Map properties, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        Map nonNullProperties = properties == null ? new HashMap() : properties;
        String name = emName;
        if (emName == null) {
            name = "";
        }

        JPAInitializer initializer = this.initializationHelper.getInitializer(classLoader, (Map)nonNullProperties);
        EntityManagerSetupImpl emSetupImpl = null;
        boolean isNew = false;

        String uniqueName;
        String sessionName;
        SEPersistenceUnitInfo factory;
        try {
            factory = initializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(name, (Map)nonNullProperties, this.initializationHelper);
            if (factory == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (initializer.isPersistenceUnitUniquelyDefinedByName()) {
                uniqueName = name;
            } else {
                uniqueName = initializer.createUniquePersistenceUnitName(factory);
            }

            sessionName = EntityManagerSetupImpl.getOrBuildSessionName((Map)nonNullProperties, factory, uniqueName);
            synchronized(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.emSetupImpls) {
                emSetupImpl = EntityManagerFactoryProvider.getEntityManagerSetupImpl(sessionName);
                if (emSetupImpl == null) {
                    if (EntityManagerFactoryProvider.initialEmSetupImpls != null) {
                        emSetupImpl = (EntityManagerSetupImpl)EntityManagerFactoryProvider.initialEmSetupImpls.remove(uniqueName);
                        if (emSetupImpl != null) {
                            emSetupImpl.changeSessionName(sessionName);
                            factory.setClassLoader(classLoader);
                        }
                    }

                    if (emSetupImpl == null) {
                        emSetupImpl = initializer.callPredeploy(factory, (Map)nonNullProperties, this.initializationHelper, uniqueName, sessionName);
                    }

                    emSetupImpl.predeploy(emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitInfo(), (Map)nonNullProperties);
                    EntityManagerFactoryProvider.addEntityManagerSetupImpl(sessionName, emSetupImpl);
                    isNew = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception var18) {
            throw PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(classLoader, var18);
        }

        if (!isNew) {
            if (!uniqueName.equals(emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitUniqueName())) {
                throw PersistenceUnitLoadingException.sessionNameAlreadyInUse(sessionName, uniqueName, emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitUniqueName());
            }

            boolean undeployed = false;
            synchronized(emSetupImpl) {
                if (emSetupImpl.isUndeployed()) {
                    undeployed = true;
                }

                emSetupImpl.predeploy(emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitInfo(), (Map)nonNullProperties);
            }

            if (undeployed) {
                return this.createEntityManagerFactory(emName, properties, classLoader);
            }
        }

        factory = null;

        try {
            EntityManagerFactoryImpl factory = new EntityManagerFactoryImpl(emSetupImpl, (Map)nonNullProperties);
            if (emSetupImpl.shouldGetSessionOnCreateFactory((Map)nonNullProperties)) {
                factory.getServerSession();
            }

            return factory;
        } catch (RuntimeException var15) {
            if (factory != null) {
                factory.close();
            } else {
                emSetupImpl.undeploy();
            }

            throw var15;
        }
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
        Map nonNullProperties = properties == null ? new HashMap() : properties;
        EntityManagerSetupImpl emSetupImpl = null;
        boolean isNew = false;
        ClassTransformer transformer = null;
        String uniqueName = PersistenceUnitProcessor.buildPersistenceUnitName(info.getPersistenceUnitRootUrl(), info.getPersistenceUnitName());
        String sessionName = EntityManagerSetupImpl.getOrBuildSessionName((Map)nonNullProperties, info, uniqueName);
        synchronized(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.emSetupImpls) {
            emSetupImpl = EntityManagerFactoryProvider.getEntityManagerSetupImpl(sessionName);
            if (emSetupImpl == null) {
                emSetupImpl = new EntityManagerSetupImpl(uniqueName, sessionName);
                isNew = true;
                emSetupImpl.setIsInContainerMode(true);
                transformer = emSetupImpl.predeploy(info, (Map)nonNullProperties);
                EntityManagerFactoryProvider.addEntityManagerSetupImpl(sessionName, emSetupImpl);
            }
        }

        if (!isNew) {
            if (!uniqueName.equals(emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitUniqueName())) {
                throw PersistenceUnitLoadingException.sessionNameAlreadyInUse(sessionName, uniqueName, emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitUniqueName());
            }

            boolean undeployed = false;
            synchronized(emSetupImpl) {
                if (emSetupImpl.isUndeployed()) {
                    undeployed = true;
                }

                transformer = emSetupImpl.predeploy(emSetupImpl.getPersistenceUnitInfo(), (Map)nonNullProperties);
            }

            if (undeployed) {
                return this.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(info, properties);
            }
        }

        if (transformer != null) {
            info.addTransformer(transformer);
        }

        EntityManagerFactoryImpl factory = new EntityManagerFactoryImpl(emSetupImpl, (Map)nonNullProperties);
        if (emSetupImpl.shouldGetSessionOnCreateFactory((Map)nonNullProperties)) {
            factory.getServerSession();
        }

        return factory;
    }

    public ProviderUtil getProviderUtil() {
        return this;
    }

    public LoadState isLoadedWithoutReference(Object entity, String attributeName) {
        return entity instanceof PersistenceWeaved ? this.isLoadedWithReference(entity, attributeName) : LoadState.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public LoadState isLoadedWithReference(Object entity, String attributeName) {
        Iterator setups = EntityManagerFactoryProvider.getEmSetupImpls().values().iterator();

        while(setups.hasNext()) {
            EntityManagerSetupImpl setup = (EntityManagerSetupImpl)setups.next();
            if (setup.isDeployed()) {
                Boolean isLoaded = EntityManagerFactoryImpl.isLoaded(entity, setup.getSession());
                if (isLoaded != null) {
                    if (isLoaded && attributeName != null) {
                        isLoaded = EntityManagerFactoryImpl.isLoaded(entity, attributeName, setup.getSession());
                    }

                    if (isLoaded != null) {
                        return isLoaded ? LoadState.LOADED : LoadState.NOT_LOADED;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return LoadState.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public LoadState isLoaded(Object entity) {
        return entity instanceof PersistenceWeaved ? this.isLoadedWithReference(entity, (String)null) : LoadState.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

The above is the interface and implementation of PersistenceProvider.
Can't see any mismatch

Comment: Looks like you've setup the resource as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30652644/496099 but then are adding another resource to javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar, and then a javax.persistence.api dependency? The combination of the two is likely causing different class loaders to be involved and why PersistenceProvider can't be matched to PersistenceProvider.

Comment: I add the interface andimplementation of PersistenceProvider.  Any ideas to solve this problem. I don’t know why it caused the mismatch. tks

Comment: It isn't, your duplication of the parent spi.PersistenceProvider class on the path is allowing it to be loaded by different loaders. Remove the duplicate spi.PersistenceProvider definitions. You added in the <exclude path="javax/**" /> so that the spi.PersistenceProvider class within the EclipseLink jar isn't picked up, but then added <resource-root path="javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar"/> which is the same thing.